# Specify bootstrap version in Angular platform-browser-dynamic

Tags: angular

I have taken over a project, it has now been upgraded to angular 11 but the bootstrap version is showing as 4.x, and we want to use bootstrap 5, there is no bootstap module in the project, bootstrap is only referenced coming from platformBrowserDynamic.

When looking about I couldn't find much [documentation](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser-dynamic/platformBrowserDynamic) on the package.

How it is currently used:

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
```

Is it possible to specify the version of bootstrap that `@angular/platform-browser-dynamic"` will use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)` is not related to `Twitter Bootstrap`.

The way we use `Bootstrap` with an `Angular` application is to add `Bootstrap` to your `package.json` file, specify the version you need here:

```
"bootstrap": "5.0.0-beta3"
```

Then you can create a main.scss file which imports Bootstrap:

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

html, body {
   ....
}
```

Don't forget to add your main.scss file in the angular.json file:

```
    "styles": [
      "src/styles/main.scss",
    ],
```

You could just point to the `Bootstrap` module directory in the `angular.json` file, but importing Boostrap's scss in your main.scss allows you to also use the Bootstrap variables and overwrite bootstrap defaults and then compile Bootstrap on the fly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yeah I'll try adding directly, there's no module of bootstrap which I've never come across before.